# Determine network congestion, min required gas/gas price based on current conditions

Tags: transactions, gas-price

Say I have an application that is making some low priority transactions.  I'd like to keep them as low priority as possible without having them take 20+ minutes or poof and disappear. What's the best technique to determine the current network conditions? For example, some nights 1 gwei gets a transaction through within a couple minutes. Other nights, 2 gwei takes 25 minutes to go through. What's the best way to determine the gas price and gas for my transactions? Can I only use the "eth_gasPrice" method, or is there something else I should be aware of?

Comment: Even eth_gasPrice is not promising enough. https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key tool for keeping up with gas price is: http://ethgasstation.info/

It isn't ideal, but it's a good rough place to start.

**Manual Review**

See the SafeLow price on the home page, and much more detailed info along the sidebar.

**API access**

There is a json API that includes SafeLow here:
http://ethgasstation.info/json/ethgasAPI.json

*I am unaffiliated with the site*

Comment: I didn't know they had a "safe low", nice.  Time to see if there is an API for that site's tool.  I'd like to get this data programmatically since network performance varies from day to day.  I'd like my app to adjust to the network rather than have hard coded "safe lows".

Comment: Great thanks!  I never found that API.  I was scraping their web page for the safe low (which isn't ideal).